Is destroying a nomination pool not working?
From what I can tell destroying of a nomination pool isn't working correctly on Polkadot. After setting the state to destroying. Unbonding + withdrawing all member's dot. Halting nomination of all validators. It won't let me unbond my funds below the 500 minimum mark, which is the last step in destroying as far as I know.
I've attempted this both on the polkadot staking dashboard and using the extrinsic nominationpools.unbond.
Am I doing something wrong?

The step I am guessing you are missing is that the pool must also be configured to chill prior to being destroyed. See here.

This worked! Thank you. Also, this functionality is missing on the staking dashboard it appears.

chill is used on staking dashboard when the pool stops all nominations. Afaik this is working as intended, but we can always revise to make it more obvious if it is a blocker on destroying a pool.
